# Узнать, открыта ли экранная клавиатура

Tags: android

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать проверку в условии, открыта ли экранная клавиатура?

P.S.
У меня работает этот вариант:

```
public boolean Keyboard_visible;
...

final View activityRootView = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
    activityRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            Rect r = new Rect();
            //r will be populated with the coordinates of your view that area still visible.
            activityRootView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
            int heightDiff = activityRootView.getRootView().getHeight() - (r.bottom - r.top);
            if (heightDiff < activityRootView.getRootView().getHeight() / 4 ) { // if more than 100 pixels, its probably a keyboard...
                Keyboard_visible = false;  // hide
            }else{
                Keyboard_visible = true; // show
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150078/how-to-check-visibility-of-software-keyboard-in-android?page=1&tab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 3):

```
private int maxRootViewHeight = 0;
private int currentRootViewHeight = 0;

rootView.getViewTreeObserver()
.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        currentRootViewHeight = rootView.getHeight();
        if (currentRootViewHeight > maxRootViewHeight) {
            maxRootViewHeight = currentRootViewHeight;
        }
    }
});

if (currentRootViewHeight >= maxRootViewHeight) {
// Закрыта
} else {
// Открыта
}
```